# Package not updating after building in local (AEM)

Tags: aem

is anyone here know why my AEM package is not updating after building it on git bash? This happened after I moved my workspace folder. Please someone help.

Current version of my package is 48.0.0, and after building successfully the repo in git bash, I checked again in package manager and it still 48.0.0, it should be 49.0.0 since the pom.xml I build is 49.0.0.

Please someone help. Thank you!

Comment: How are you building the package, what command do you use? Are you getting any error messages? Did you check the logs?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: *"48.0.0, it should be 49.0.0 since the pom.xml"* - tried to restart your AEM? often times hot reloading does not work as expected..

Comment: Did you change the filter definitions? Are you deploying via Maven? Please provide the logs when the command is executed, if there is invalid data in the package, AEM will refuse to install it and the logs will give you a hint of where is the issue.